# Importing specific pictures into Excel from local folder

Tags: vba, excel

I'm totally new to VBA and I'm muddling my way through a challenge at work.

I'm looking for a simple code to import specific pictures from a folder into a into a worksheet. I'm really struggling with the coding language and a lot is going over my head.

I basically want the macro to look at all references in column A and return the associated picture into the adjacent column from a folder on my drive. The reference in column A will be the file name, without the extension.

```
Option Explicit

Sub AddOlEObject()

    Dim mainWorkBook As Workbook
    Dim Folderpath As String
    Dim fso, NoOfFiles, listfiles, fls, strCompFilePath
    Dim counter


  Dim shp As Shape
  For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    If shp.Type = msoPicture Then shp.Delete
  Next shp

    Set mainWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Folderpath = "C:\Users\grahamb\Desktop\TEST"
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    NoOfFiles = fso.GetFolder(Folderpath).Files.Count
    Set listfiles = fso.GetFolder(Folderpath).Files
    For Each fls In listfiles
       strCompFilePath = Folderpath & "\" & Trim(fls.Name)
        If strCompFilePath <> "" Then


            If (InStr(1, strCompFilePath, "jpg", vbTextCompare) > 1 _
            Or InStr(1, strCompFilePath, "jpeg", vbTextCompare) > 1 _
            Or InStr(1, strCompFilePath, "png", vbTextCompare) > 1) Then
                 counter = counter + 1
                  Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & counter).Value = fls.Name
                  Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & counter).ColumnWidth = 25
                Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & counter).RowHeight = 100
                Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & counter).Activate
                Call insert(strCompFilePath, counter)
                Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Function insert(PicPath, counter)

    With ActiveSheet.Pictures.insert(PicPath)


        With .ShapeRange
            .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
            .Width = 50
            .Height = 70
        End With
        .Left = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & counter).Left
        .Top = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & counter).Top
        .Placement = 1
        .PrintObject = True
    End With
End Function
```

The challenges I'm having are:

-This macro imports all pictures from the given folder. I only want specific pictures referenced in column A.
-This macro deletes all pictures, but I want to retain buttons.

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers
G

Answer (score 0):

Consider this.

```
Sub InsertPics()
Dim fPath As String, fName As String
Dim r As Range, rng As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
fPath = "C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\"
Set rng = Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
i = 1

For Each r In rng
    fName = Dir(fPath)
    Do While fName <> ""
        If fName = r.Value Then
            With ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(fPath & fName)
                .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
                Set px = .ShapeRange
                If .ShapeRange.Width > Rows(i).Columns(2).Width Then .ShapeRange.Width = Columns(2).Width
                    With Cells(i, 2)
                        px.Top = .Top
                        px.Left = .Left
                        .RowHeight = px.Height
                    End With
            End With
        End If
        fName = Dir
    Loop
    i = i + 1
Next r
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Note: you need the file extension, such as ',jpg', or whatever you are using, so you can match on that.